# Can I select more than one visual section with VIM?

Tags: vim

Lets say I've got 10 lines:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Baz
4. Quz
5. Qaz
```

How could I select lines 1-3 and than 4-5.

Comment: Isn't that identical to selecting lines 1-5?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use registers, because there's no way to highlight more than a single block at a time without using plugins.

The structure is <kbd>"</kbd>`<register><action>`.

**Basic example:**

Do a visual selection with either `<C-v>` (block) or `<S-v>` (line). Select your first block.

[image]

Yank/cut it into a register with `"qy` or `"qx`. `q` can be any letter, it's just the identifier of the register.

[image]

Do the same thing for the next block, but with a different register. `"wy` or `"wx`.

[image]

Now, both selections are in registers `q` and `w` respectively. Navigate to your targeted location and paste them with `"qp` or `"wp`.

[image] [image]

If you want to append the contents of the `w` register into the `q` register, you can do the following in command mode.

`:let @q .= @w`

You can also yank multiple lines without even entering visual mode. The command is `"<register><number><action><movement>`. Say if you want to yank the current row to 3 rows down into register `z`, type `"z3yj"`. You should see a `4 lines yanked` confirmation in the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Using registers would be the best way to go about it. But if you insist on having non-contiguous visual selection, then here's a plugin that does that -

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953